# How does the method Scanner.nextInt() works compare to Scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java

I've just started Java recently. There's an exercise that ask me to split and display the number separated by spacebar. 
The standard input is basically like this:

```
2
2 2
```

The first line is the number of integers in the array.
The second line is the array
This is the first block of code that I use

```
   import java.util.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=reader.nextInt();
        String []s=reader.nextLine().split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<=t-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The "+(i+1) +" number is "+s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When compile and run it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

However when I change the the reader.nextInt() to reader.nextLine() and parse it into integer it works perfectly fine

```
import java.util.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        String []s=reader.nextLine().split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<=t-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("The "+(i+1) +" number is "+s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the output looks like

```
The 1 number is 2
The 2 number is 2
```

So why doesn't it work with reader.nextInt() ?

Edit about the reading the Line character, I still don't get it. It reads the string normally

Answer (score 0):

```
int t=reader.nextInt();
```

Reads a 2.

```
reader.nextLine()
```

Reads to the next newline character.

Calling it *again* will read `2 2`, as expected.

Check the content of `s`. It's likely empty, or doesn't have 2 elements, thus the error

When you read the line twice, you consume the newline

For more info, see  [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: In the first scenario, If I simply change the s into String s=reader.nextLine(), it still shows 2 2 however when split, it is unable to split properly

Comment: You are welcome to post another question with your problem. `"2 2".split(" ")` works for me, though